# Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EXECUTION' on deployment phase

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa-dotnet

What is wrong here, we need a fix?

For a page 'navigation' and 'sitemap' we have metadata on the page for re-scheduling.
The first (direct) publish succeed and it re-schedules (handled by the event system method)
The scheduled new job starts as expected but fails with

```
SqlExceptionHelper - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EXECUTION_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EXECUTION'. The duplicate key value is (tcm:0-4543761-66560).
```

It succeeds in publishing but not in deployment, (also the event system is not accessed this time).

```
2021-11-22 15:25:20,374 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-124] HybridStateStore - Creating new execution entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,374 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-123] HybridStateStore - Creating new execution entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,374 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-124] SqlExceptionHelper - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EXECUTION_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EXECUTION'. The duplicate key value is (tcm:0-4543761-66560).
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,374 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-124] ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,374 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-125] HybridStateStore - Creating new pipeline entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Bootstrap
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,389 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-129] HybridStateStore - Creating new step entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Bootstrap and step id: TridionUnzipStep
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,405 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-129] HybridStateStore - Found step entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Bootstrap and step id: TridionUnzipStep
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,421 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-130] HybridStateStore - Found pipeline entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Bootstrap
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,421 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-132] HybridStateStore - Creating new pipeline entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Wait
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,436 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-133] HybridStateStore - Creating new step entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Wait and step id: TridionWaitStep
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,436 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-133] HybridStateStore - Found step entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Wait and step id: TridionWaitStep
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,452 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-122] HybridStateStore - Found pipeline entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Wait
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,452 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-124] HybridStateStore - Creating new pipeline entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Cleanup
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,467 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-126] HybridStateStore - Creating new step entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Cleanup and step id: TridionCleanupStep
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,467 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-126] HybridStateStore - Found step entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560, pipeline id: Tridion-Cleanup and step id: TridionCleanupStep
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,483 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-128] HybridStateStore - Found pipeline entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Cleanup
    2021-11-22 15:25:20,483 DEBUG [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-125] HybridStateStore - Found execution entity for execution id: tcm:0-4543761-66560
```

UPDATE-1: poller and action message.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Double-check if there are any failed leftover records in the state store database tables?

Comment: No rows. Db itself contains 5 tables. Only State_Tds_db_Info has 1 row with info (DB_VERSION 11.0.0.0, LAST_MODIFIED Jan 21 2021). CD receives the deployer .zip in folder D:\SDL_TridionServices\Staging\abc\Deployer\Binaries. a transaction.xml contains <?xml version="1.0"?><Transaction Id="tcm:0-4543761-66560"><Control>COMMIT</Control>
</Transaction>

Comment: You said it works fine for normal publishing but fails only for rescheduled publishing is that correct?

Comment: Frits are you facing this issue on production  environment or non production environment if its production can you try to reproduce the issue on lower environment and we can check if its because of event system scheduling causing this . It works when you publish manually correct.

Comment: Anand. It occurs on all OTAP, so can reproduce it. For sitemap and new also navigation. It can be easy tested when you schedule it direct and the metadata will schedule it because of time for 5-10 min later. Second publish fails.

Comment: It fails for both dxa and not dxa.

Comment: Try to get the logs  and see if you can raise a ticket with support for them to further look into this issue .

Comment: Thanks. We will do that.